# Check if executed trigger executes another trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a trigger on a parent object which manipulates the child objects.  However (and as predicted), when the parent trigger modifies the child trigger executes.

Is there a way for me to stop the child trigger from executing if triggered from the system vs a user.

```
Example: 

Trigger is fired on parent and child records are modified
Child trigger starts:  If trigger.StartedFromTrigger then exit else run trigger
```

OR if there is a way where I can complete my update of the parent record within the parent record trigger AND then run the update of the children that would be an option too.  Perhaps I would have to use AFTER UPDATE for that one.

Comment: You create a static variable in your trigger. Apex static variables persist their values throughout the transaction. If the value is set to `true` in the parent object's trigger, it will be persisted through the end of the child object's trigger

Comment: how would I reference the static variable from the parent in my child trigger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you implement a handler pattern, it is not very difficult to use `static` flags for this level of control.

```
public with sharing class ChildTriggerHandler
{
    public static Boolean hasFiredParentTrigger = false;
    public void beforeInsert()
    {
        // unprotected logic
        if (!hasFiredParentTrigger)
        {
            // protected logic
        }
    }
}

public with sharing class ParentTriggerHandler
{
    public ParentTriggerHandler()
    {
        ChildTriggerHandler.hasFiredParentTrigger = true;
    }
}
```

---

The handler pattern I typically use looks like:

```
public with sharing class MyObjectTriggerHandler
{
    @TestVisible static Boolean bypassTrigger = false; // can disable for tests!
    final List<MyObject__c> newRecords;
    final Map<Id, MyObject__c> oldMap;
    public MyObjectTriggerHandler(List<MyObject__c> newRecords, Map<Id, MyObject__c> oldMap)
    {
        this.newRecords = newRecords;
        this.oldMap = oldMap;
    }

    public void beforeInsert()
    {
        if (bypassTrigger) return;

        MyObjectServices.someAction(newRecords);
    }
    public void afterInsert()
    {
        if (bypassTrigger) return;

        // etc.
    }
}
```

Then in your trigger:

```
trigger MyObject on MyObject__c (before insert, after insert)
{
    MyObjectTriggerHandler handle = new MyObjectTriggerHandler(trigger.new, trigger.oldMap);

    if (trigger.isBefore)
    {
        if (trigger.isInsert) handle.beforeInsert();
        if (trigger.isInsert) handle.beforeUpdate();
    }
    if (trigger.isAfter)
    {
        if (trigger.isInsert) handle.afterInsert();
        if (trigger.isInsert) handle.afterUpdate();
    }
}
```

Comment: are these their own classes or one class or in the trigger?  Also, is ChildTriggerHandler = MyTriggerNameHandler?

Comment: Separate top level classes. One handler for each object. @tjc

Comment: so I created 2 class files which leaves me with 4 files:  ParentTrigger, ParentTriggerHandler, ChildTrigger, ChildTriggerHandler.  Is that correct?

Comment: @tjcinnamon Exactly! Typically I add a service layer, so three files to implement the whole pattern, but each one has a very dedicated [concern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). However, your handler pattern of choice is not the key concern here. Rather, it is that you need a top level class so that you can actually store that static flag somewhere.

Comment: perfect.  So in my ChildTriggerHandler what do I do with protected logic vs unprotected logic?  All of my logic is in my ChildTrigger?

Comment: @tjc The unprotected logic will run whether or not you originated from the parent trigger. The protected logic will not run if the flag is set (which should only happen from the parent trigger).

Comment: sure, but what do I put in there.  Do I move my entire trigger to that class if so, then what's in the trigger?  If not, what would I put in there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40187/discussion-between-adrian-larson-and-tjcinnamon).

Comment: Although I didn't use the service layer, I did use the handlers and it worked!  Thanks for going above and beyond!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can set a static variable in the parent trigger with appropriate values and then check in the child trigger if they were set before doing any action? Same as we do to prevent recursive action.

Comment: Ah just commented this - yes, this will work.

Comment: how would I reference the static variable from the parent in my child trigger?

Comment: You put the static variable in a class and then set it int he parent trigger. And then in the child trigger  check like - StaticLibrary.IsParentRun